# If local storage item, add class to all parent elements - vanilla js

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to add the class "active" to the parents of all input elements with the class "ct-sw-input" and the state checked if *localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark'* in pure js.

In jquery I had

```
$(".ct-sw-input").prop("checked", true).closest("label").addClass("active");
```

But in vanilla js I tried the following code and no success so far:

```
var root = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var switcher = document.getElementsByClassName('ct-sw-input');


for (var i=0; i < switcher.length; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark') {
        switcher[i].parentElement.classList.add("active");
        switcher[i].checked = true;
    } else {
        switcher[i].parentElement.classList.remove("active");
        switcher[i].checked = false;
    }   
}   

//this part works
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark') {
    root.classList.remove("light-mode");
    root.classList.add("dark-mode");        
} else {
    root.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    root.classList.add("light-mode");
}
```

HTML

```
<label class="switch" title="Dark Skin">                    
   <input type="checkbox" id="ct-sw" class="ct-sw-input">       
   <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/costheme/bj2p54f8/)

Comment: can you provide html structure also?

Comment: You need to remove the period in `'.ct-sw-input'`; the class name is `ct-sw-input` but you're using the selector.

Comment: change `getElementsByClassName` to `Document.querySelectorAll`or remove dot from `.ct-sw-inpu`

Comment: I tried both .querySelectorAll and getElementsByClassName , with or without the dot and still not working.

Comment: Please add mentioned CSS

Comment: It is working properly: https://codepen.io/ikiK_Cro/pen/YzqeoQG remove local with `localStorage.removeItem("theme");`

Comment: Strange, I don't get the same results in my example. I'll create a jsfiddle example now.

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/costheme/bj2p54f8/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/usd75z8e/1/ You can not have that code in your `head`... You are not fetching any elements when you pout it before you render DOM, ether copy that code at end of body or wrap it in `document ready`

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need that code in the  <head> to avoid flashing the white background color on page refresh.

Comment: Complicity different problem, code it self works. When you have `Document.querySelectorAll` or anything like that that on load try to get elements, it needs to be after DOM has loaded, if its before, there is nothing to catch. There are topics here on SO that deal with themes and fleshing before change of it on load. Cant remember are they solved.

Comment: I think i solved it by making body visibility:hidden for portion of second until it gets and sests the theme, then show body. That way there's no flash.

Comment: body visibility:hidden is not the way I need. Anyway, I got the same results by targeting the elements in CSS based on the <html> class and switched from checkbox to using a div or button.